# How to connect to sqlite3 database using python

Tags: python

I am a complete noob when it comes to staging connections using python. How I understand it is, python already comes pre-packaged with sqlite3. I am using python 3.8.5.
Here is my attempt

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("\python\Lib\sqlite3")
```

It returns error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Comment: `\python\Lib\sqlite3` is not a valid path name.

Comment: Did you read this already? https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. So I just need to supply a filename where the database objects are stored.

I was incorrectly thinking that I would need to supply the folder location to the database.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
```

which stores the database objects in the test.db file within the python folder.

Answer (score 0):

You don't connect to the package, you connect to a database file.

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('path/to/database.db')
```

Full info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).